# Not an autocomplete WPF Combobox (but maybe close)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, filter, combobox

I have an `ObservableCollection` and a `ComboBox` binded to it. What I want to achieve is to filter that `ObservableCollection` and only let the `ComboBox` display the filtered items. Later somewhere I have a `foreach (item in ComboBox) loop`. The filtering should be by writing some letters, and if the name property of the items of that are in `ObservableCollection` doesn't contain that letters, remove that item.

I know there is a way of typing directly in the ComboBox with `IsEditable` property, but for this example let's just use an additional TextBox for the user's input.

For practice I'm doing it with a `ObservableCollection<string>` (and not with a my `<myClass>` that has more properties.)

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        names= new ObservableCollection<string>();

        names.Add("Harry");
        names.Add("Ron");
        names.Add("Einstein");
        names.Add("Frodo");
        names.Add("Spiderman");

        myComboBox.DataContext = this;
    }

         public ObservableCollection<string> names{ get; set; }
         public ObservableCollection<string> filteredNames{ get; set; }
```

I've created this method:

```
 void toFilter()
      {
      filteredNames=new ObservableCollection<string>(names.Where(name=> name.StartsWith(myTextBox.Text)));
      }
```

And in the `text changed`:

```
private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                toFilter();
            }
            myComboBox.DataContext = this; //Obviously doesn't work
        }
```

So I want to keep the original collection intact (`names`), and display `filteredNames` when something is typed in the text box. Should I bind directly the combobox to the `filteredNames` (initially equal to `names`) and then remove by looping the names that don't match the text box input each time `myTextBox_TextChanged`?

Other approach would be to change the bind of the comboBox when something is typed from `names` to `filteredNames`.

How could this be achieved the easy way?

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestion of using CollectionViewSource, it worked perfectly in this example, but in my real program I'm having some issues. I've reduced the problematic part to this (from XAML Lover solution)

```
view.Filter = delegate(object o)
                        {

                            if (o.ToString().StartsWith(myTextBox.Text))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;

                        };
```

I've seen the next behaviour:
If I don't write anything, once the file is loaded the comboBox is populated with data and everything is okey. If I write anything different from  "Unico.Canal" all data is gone from the combobox (Unico is my namespace, and Canal is the class of the CollectionViewSource), I've realized that by trial and error.
The code is bit a mess (and very long) because I have the read file method there, do you see something that could give me that error? I think I haven't put the code in the right place. Could someone explain me what exactly is doing that "delegate" and how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper approach in WPF for filtering is to use CollectionViewSource. ICollectionView is the primary data object for any WPF Items Controls, that allow flexibility like sorting, grouping and filtering. Get the default view from your collection property.

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.names);
```

Set a Predicate to the Filter property, that will be executed over all the items in collection.

```
view.Filter = delegate(object o)
            {
                if (o.ToString().StartsWith(textbox.Text))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };
```

Set the view to the ComboBox ItemsSource,

```
myComboBox.ItemsSource = view;
```

On TextChanged event refresh the view to update the combo box.

```
    private void Textbox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ICollectionView)myComboBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement it to a Editable combobox? Is "TextInput" of the combobox the same as "OnTextChanged" of the textbox?

Comment: TextInput is not equivalent to OnTextChanged. Instead use TextBoxBase.TextChanged event.

Comment: I'm having some unexpected behaviour. I've edited my question, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CollectionViewSource and set it's source to your names collection.

In your viewModel you will set up a collectionViewSource like so;

```
CollectionViewSource myCollectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
myCollectionViewSource.Source = names;
```

You need to set up a predicate to filter the items in your collectionViewSource

```
myCollectionViewSource.View.Filter = new Predicate(this.MyFilter);
public bool MyFilter(string item)
{
  // put whatever filtering logic you have in here
  return item.StartsWith(myTextBox.Text);
}
```

Then expose your collectionViewSource as a property to the view.

```
public CollectionViewSource MyCollectionViewSource 
{
  get
  {
    return myCollectionViewSource;
  }
  set
  {
    myCollectionViewSource = value;
    // make sure to raise INotifyPropertyChanged here
  }
}
```

Then in your XAML your ComboBox will look like this;

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionViewSource.View}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly ,
i would change the this

```
public ObservableCollection<string> FilteredNames{ get; set; }
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<string> FilteredNames
{ 
    get
       {
            if(IsNamesFilterd)
            {
                return _filteredNames;
            }
            else
            {
                return _names ;
            }
       }
 }
```

with changing the boolean condition in the event handler code.
also NotifyPropertyChanged after changing the Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ICollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) as a data-bound property type instead of `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
namesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(names);
namesView.Filter = item =>
{
    if (myTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        return ((string)item).StartsWith(myTextBox.Text);
    }
    return true;
};

private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    namesView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Does this work with a more general collection? In myClass I'm not only interested in viewing the names. The name is only for the user, but internally I will be working with properties of that objects <myClass>.

Comment: Yes, it does. `ICollectionView` isn't for built-in types only.

Comment: I tried it hard, but still can't adapt this for my custom class. I want to filter its name property. I've posted a separated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816983/filtering-collectionviewsource