# Filtering CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, filter, collectionviewsource

I want to make a `ComboBox` bound to my data, with a **filter**. For that I've created a `TextBox` and a `ComboBox`. In the code behind I read a file and generate objects of class Channel that are stored as items of the `ComboBox`. Although the compiler throws no error the filtering doesn't work properly. If I write something the data is gone, if I erase, it's back. After trying and trying I've realized that if I started typing "myNamespace.myChannel" (Unico.Canal) the data remained, but don't filter. Strange behaviour, indeed. I suspect that I've put something in wrong place.

[image][image][image]

(for better understanding I've translated the code, Canal=Channel)

Here is the scheme of my code:

```
namespace Unico
{
        public partial class ControlesArchivo : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public ControlesArchivo()
            {

                InitializeComponent();        
            }

    public ObservableCollection<Channel> myListChannels //with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented. But I think I don't need it.

     private void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

              File loadedFile = new File();
              loadedFile.read(); //Generates a bunch of data in lists.

              foreach (Channel mychan in loadedFile.channels) //Just duplicating the data (maybe this can be avoided)
                   {
                    myListChannels.Add(mychan);
                   }

         var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.miListaDeCanales);
                        view.Filter = delegate(object o)
                        {
                            if (o.ToString().Contains(myTextBox.Text)) //Delicate place
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        };

                myComboBox.ItemsSource = view;
     DataContext = this;
    }


     private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {


                       ((ICollectionView)myComboBox.ItemsSource).Refresh();
                       myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

            }


      }
    }
```

The data is bound in XAML with:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding view}"
```

EDIT: I think I know where is the problem: I'm not specifing the property to filter. I mean, what you see in the ComboBox is the property `channelName` of the `class Channel` listed in myListChannels. When I'm setting the filter, shouldn't I let know what I'm filtering? How could I write this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct.

I'm assuming with your translations,

```
public ObservableCollection<Channel> myListChannels;
```

is actually

```
public ObservableCollection<Canal> miListaDeCanales;
```

with the class `Canal` in the namespace `Unico`

**Update:**

In your filter try using the property that is rendered in the `ComboBox` than use the `ToString()` on the `object`(`o`) if you've not overridden `ToString()` from `System.Object`.

try switching

```
if (o.ToString().Contains(myTextBox.Text))
```

to

```
if (((Canal)o).NameProperty.Contains(myTextBox.Text))
```

^^ that should fix your issue.

Do you have a `DataTemplate` for `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` in xaml. That will explain why you see the valid value rendered in the `ComboBox`, else all the `ComboBoxItem`'s will also render as `Unico.Canal`